# What does through intent and programmatically mean?

Tags: java, android

i'm searching for codes for my Android application and i encounter these two words. it says that i can do this by INTENT or i can do this PROGRAMATICALLY?

what's the difference between the two by the way? thanks

Comment: Do you mean android-intent, or user's intent to do something? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

"Programatically" means that something will be done in the Java code. Most commonly this is used when referring to creating or setting properties on a `View`. When a `View` is created through xml then the xml can't be changed (but the `View` can be programatically in the Java code). If it is created programatically then you don't create it in xml before compiling, instead it is done through Java code.

`Intent` is an Android class used to start an `Activity` access settings and other such things.

[Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I click on the button save (by intent), the software should validate the input field (programmatically) and if the form is invalid, a popup message should appear (programmatically).

By intent means user will decide what to happen.
Programmatically means program will decide what to happen.